# How to use Google Calendar API credentials from objects

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I want to use object for Google Calendar API credentials, not from a JSON.

I have tried creating a dictionary with the Client ID and Client Secret.

You can see that [here](https://bitbucket.org/kingmray/django-google-calendar/src/master/calendar_api/calendar_api.py)

Instead of the `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'calender_key.json'` I want to get the client credentials from an object.

Comment: Could you please post your own code so we can help you with that?

Answer (score 0):

The example you cited calls `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name()`.

There is also `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict()` whose docs say:

> Factory constructor from parsed JSON keyfile.
>
> ```
> Args:
>      keyfile_dict: dict-like object, The parsed dictionary-like object
>                    containing the contents of the JSON keyfile.
> ```

So, if you can provide the credentials in the same format as parsed from a JSON file, you can use this method.

The remaining arguments are the same as for `from_json_keyfile_name()`.